# Slowdown when processing large number of files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, performance

I'm trying to create a large array containing about 64000 objects. The objects are truncated SHA256 digests of files.

The files are in 256 subdirectories (named 00 - ff) each containing about 256 files (varies slightly for each). Each file size is between around 1.5KB and 2KB.

The code looks like this:

```
require 'digest'
require 'cfpropertylist'

A = Array.new

Dir.glob('files/**') do |dir|
    puts "Processing dir #{dir}"
    Dir.glob("#{dir}/*.bin") do |file|
        sha256 = Digest::SHA256.file file
        A.push(CFPropertyList::Blob.new(sha256.digest[0..7]))
    end
end

plist = A.to_plist({:plist_format => CFPropertyList::List::FORMAT_XML, :formatted => true})

File.write('hashes.plist', plist)
```

If I process 16 directories (replacing 'files/**' with 'files/0*' in the above), the time it takes on my machine is 0m0.340s.

But if I try to process all of them, the processing speed drastically reduce after about 34 directories have been processed.

This is on the latest OS X, using the stock ruby.
The machine is a mid-2011 iMac with 12GB memory and 3.4 GHz Intel Core i7.

The limiting factor does not seem to be the Array size: since if I remove the sha256 processing and just store the filenames instead, there is no slowdown.

Is there anything I can do better or to track the issue?  I don't have another OS or machine available at the moment to test if this is an OS X or machine specific thing.

Comment: "Is there anything I can do better or to track the issue" Yes. Profile it with ruby-prof. https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof

Comment: meh, I figuring out that it is just the disk cache. I must have run the script several times while debugging it so the first files being processed where in the disk cache and read quickly. After letting the script longer and longer, the slowdown occurred later and later. Also, that machine has a spinning disk. I tried it on a less powerful mac with an SSD and didn't noticed slowdown even on first run.

Answer (score 0):

This is a disk/FS caching issue. After running the script to completion, and rerunning again the slowdown mostly disappeared. Also using another computer with SSD didn't show a slowdown.